# Does Microsoft Visual C++ support WebAssembly as a target?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, webassembly

I know many people are using Rust and a few other languages to experiment with WebAssembly.

And I know that people using WebAssembly with C/C++ are mostly using Clang/LLVM.

But I can't seem to find any information at all on whether MSVC can compile C/C++ to wasm binaries, whether there's any kind of beta or developer preview, or whether it's on a future roadmap or feature request, etc.

I know Edge supports wasm and Microsoft is listed as one of WebAssembly's developers on the [wasm Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly).

But what about generating wasm from MSVC? Any info on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ now supports WebAssembly using some toolchains like llvm/emscripten, but VC++ does not support it currently. The good news is that VC++ developers have noticed this:

> We will do some preliminary checks to make sure we can proceed further. (2018/12/14)

For more information, you can check out these links: [Targeting WebAssembly with C++ in Visual Studio IDE?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/407554/targeting-webassembly-with-c-in-visual-studio-ide.html) and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/457758/add-emscriptenwebassembly-support.html

Comment: Actually some MS person [more recently replied on one of those threads](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/705983/view.html) that they won't be supporting wasm: `Aug 22 at 06:55 PM
Thank you for your suggestion. We have no current or future plans to support this.`